# ¿Por qué mi código no se ejecuta en atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

Descargué el paquete de script y no me ejecuta el código. ¿Alguien sabe por qué? ¿Qué puedo hacer para resolver este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, creo que deberías visitar el [Tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) antes de formular una pregunta. Atom no es quién se encarga de ejecutar tu código, quizá debas intentar desde una consola. Cuándo hagas una pregunta, siempre debes tomar en cuenta de agregar con detalle todo lo que has intentado y en que parte tienes problemas.

Answer (score 5):

Por defecto no puedes ejecutar scripts en Atom.

Una alternativa para poder ejecutar scripts en Atom es utilizar [atom-script](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script)

Para instalar este paquete desde Atom, ves a *settings* y luego a *install*, en la barra buscas script y presionas el botón *Install*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Prueba con algo más sencillo para que verifiques que se instaló correctamente.

Un ejemplo en Windows:

**hello.py**

```
print("hello world")
```

Para ejecutar wn Windows presiona:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Deberías obtener algo así:

```
Python - hello.py:1
hello world
[Finished in 0.058s]
```

Sin embargo, si tu programa necesita recibir interacción del usuario creo que no es posible hasta el momento. Me parece que este paquete [hidrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) podría servir, pero hasta el momento no lo he probado

Comment: Atom no cuenta con una terminal embebida? Hay un paquete que adicione eso?

Comment: No cuenta con terminal, pero si hay varios paquetes que ofrecen esa funcionalidad aunque no los he probado. Por ejemplo [terminal-plus](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, primero asegurate de que tienes bien colocado en tu path (si es windows) la ruta para tu terminal de python.
Si tienes eso ya arreglado, primero vamos al atom, como ya han comentado en otra respuesta es cierto, atom por defecto no ejecuta en terminal, pero hay un paquete que se llama scritp, que si lo buscas en el gestor de paquetes de atom te aparecerá el de la imagen.

En mi caso como lo tengo instalado no aparece la opción de *install*, pero en tu caso si no lo tienes instalado aparecerá.

[image: Atom-script]

Una vez instalado, te vas a tu programa en python y pulsas:

`"control" + "shift" + "B"`

Debería aparecerte lo mismo que en la imagen, en caso de que no sea así, revisa tu path ya que ese error lo tuve yo también. Para comprobar si esta bien puesto.

[image: ejecutando test.py]

Para comprobar que tienes bien puesto tu path, escribe en tu terminal:

```
python /*ruta*/test.py
```

Y deberá mostrarte lo mismo que en la imagen anterior.
En caso contrario, asegurate que el path esta puesto para *Variables del sistema*.

Tendrás que tener algo parecido a esto:

```
C:\Users\Danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\
C:\Users\Danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\pyhton.exe
```

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.

Answer (score -3):

Encontre una solcion facil y sensilla.

cuando estes usando la extencion Script y al intentar ejecutar tu archivo te aparece

> No se encontr� Python; ejecuta sin argumentos para instalar desde Microsoft Store o deshabilita este acceso directo en Configuraci�n > Administrar los alias de ejecuci�n de aplicaciones.

lo unico que se tiene que hacer es mover tu archivo de donde lo tengas a la carpeta donde se instalo el python.
**Tiene que ser la misma en donde esta python.exe, no sirve en subcarpetas**

Se que hay maneras para configurar para que puedas correrlo desde donde sea, pero si apenas estas empezando y no entiendes lo que dicen, solo mueve tu archivo de lugar

Comment: Meter todos tus archivos en la carpeta donde tienes instalado python no es una práctica recomendada en absoluto. De hecho, al contrario. Imagínate que tienes varios proyectos, cómo los separas si no pueden ni estar en carpetas??? Para eso hay plugins que te permiten ejecutarlos, que funcionan mucho mejor y te permiten tener los proyectos organizados correctamente