# ¿Cómo hacer un "hola mundo" en un paquete para ATOM?

Tags: atom-editor, babeljs, coffeescript, babel, packages

Bueno, se que la pregunta es muy básica, pero es que estoy intentando hace un paquete de ejemplo con un *hola mundo* pero por mas que intento no se ejecuta el archivo main.

He leído la guia oficial de [ATOM](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/). Lo primero que hice fue crear mi paquete a través del [package generator](https://github.com/atom/package-generator) de ATOM. Al paquete le puse **activate-background-music** se me generaron todos los archivos del paquete inclusive el `package.json` con el siguiente código.

```
  {
    "name": "activate-background-music",
      "main": "./lib/activate-background-music",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "description": "A short description of your package",
      "activationCommands": {
        "atom-workspace": "activate-background-music:toggle"
      },
      "repository": "https://github.com/atom/your-name-word-count",
      "license": "MIT",
      "engines": {
        "atom": ">=1.0.0 <2.0.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
      }
   }
```

En la carpeta `lib` tengo un archivo con el mismo nombre del paquete `activate-background-music.js` con el siguiente código (que se supone que es mi función main).

```
'use babel'

module.exports = {
  activate: miFuncion() {
    console.log("Hola soy tu primer paquete para ATOM");
  }
}
```

> Más información

Cambie el archivo de `.js` a `.coffee` y su codigo actual es.

```
module.exports = activateBackgroundMusic =

  activate: (state) ->
    console.log "Hola soy tu primer paquete para ATOM"
    @subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable
    @subscriptions.add atom.commands.add "atom-workspace",
      "activate-background-music:toggle": => @toggle()

  toggle: ->
    if @active then @disable() else @enable()

  enable: ->
    @active = true

  disable: ->
    @active = false
```

Pero cuando refresco ATOM o lo abro no sucede nada, solo cundo ejecuto el comando `activate-background-music:toggle` y solo así se ejecuta mi paquete. Solo quiero saber ¿Porque mi función principal no se ejecuta? y **¿Que debo hacer para que se ejecute al iniciar el programa?.**

Comment: ¿Has revisado [¿Por qué mi código no se ejecuta en atom?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6053/65?)

Comment: @Rubén, si te fijas el no esta trabajando con un paquete para ATOM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elimina `activationCommands` del archivo `package.json` y debería activarse el paquete al arrancar Atom.

Cuando generas un paquete por defecto se crea la clave `activationCommands` en el archivo `package.json`, esto evita que el paquete se active al arrancar atom, supongo que trata de evitar recargar demasiado el editor al inicio. En el manual explica su funcionamiento: http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/package-word-count/

> **activationCommands:** an Object identifying commands that trigger your
>   package's activation. The keys are CSS selectors, the values are
>   Arrays of Strings identifying the command. The loading of your package
>   is delayed until one of these events is triggered within the
>   associated scope defined by the CSS selector. If not specified, the
>   activate() method of your main export will be called when your package
>   is loaded.

Básicamente dice que se retrasa la carga del paquete hasta que se active un evento.

En Stackoverflow he encontrado una pregunta similar con esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29309707/4994625

Comment: me ha funcionado, pero, ¿Podrías agregar más información, como a que se debe este problema. o algun enlace con mas información sobre el tema? - y Gracias.

Comment: No es un problema, al generar un paquete se crea `activationCommands` precisamente para evitar que se ejecute al arrancar. Te busco enlaces y los pongo en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @blonfu.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose recuerda que tienes una recompensa abierta que está a punto de caducar. Además de aceptar la respuesta, entrega esos preciosos puntos a blonfu si consideras que te ayudó :)

Comment: Sorry es la primera vez que realizo este tipo de preguntas. XD.